# two dropdown-boxes on one page without submit

Tags: javascript, php

I do have a problem with two dropdown boxes on one page. Cause I have to work without a submit I use the "onblur=document.getElementById.submit" in the "". This works fine but only for one dropdown box. Using the same(equal) code for both forms will result in destroying the entries of form1 when selecting an item in form2 and visa verse. 
Form-1:

```
<form id="formunit" name="formunit" method="post" action="" >

    <select name="cbo_unit" required="required" form="formunit" style="width:100pt" onblur="document.getElementById('formunit').submit();">
        <option value="0">--select--</option>
        <?php
        if ($_POST["cbo_unit"] == "MH") {
            echo "<option value=\"MH\" selected=\"selected\">Motorhome</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value=\"MH\">Motorhome</option>";
        }
        if ($_POST["cbo_unit"] == "RT") {
            echo "<option value=\"RT\" selected=\"selected\">Racetruck</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value=\"RT\">Racetruck</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['cbo_unit']) && $_POST['cbo_unit'] > '') {
            $unit = $_POST['cbo_unit']; 
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Form-2:

```
<?php
    fc_opendb("1","something",$connect);
    $dbtable = "course";
    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["connect"],"SELECT * FROM " . $dbtable . " WHERE blocked = 'no' ORDER BY matchcode ASC");
?>

<form id="formcourse" name="formcourse" method="post" action="" >

    <select name="cbo_course" required="required" form="formcourse" style="width:130pt" onblur="document.getElementById('formcourse').submit();">
        <option value="0">--select--</option>
        <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($row['matchcode'] == $_POST['cbo_course']) {
                $selected = "selected";
            } else {
                $selected = "";
            }

            echo '<option value="' . $row['matchcode'] . '"' . $selected . '>' . utf8_encode($row['name']) . ' - ' . utf8_encode($row['place']) . '</option>'."\n";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['cbo_course']) && $_POST['cbo_course'] > '') {
            $course = $_POST['cbo_course'];
        } 
        mysqli_close($GLOBALS["connect"]);
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that when you're submitting the form A you do not have the form B. One solution can be use only one Form with both select with OnBlur. This will solve probably the problem.

Comment: @Goikiu, alternatively, he could have a function with both submits and call it from both onblurs. If I understand his query at all.

Comment: @Pyromonk i don't know, it depends, if the system submit in the same page change yes :) otherwise if those are separated he need to use Sessions

Comment: both forms are on the same page ?

Comment: yes, and these are only the first two. 9 other dropdown must follow....